# Schematic of a resettable thermostat

Tags: sensors

You can put 2 or 4 or even 6 pcs of this in series to make sure at least one will work or open if it reaches say 55 degree celsius, right? And there is no resistances to consider when its close and in operation?

No exact schematic yet?

How does the inside of this looks like? I couldnt find any internal cutout in the internet.

[image]

Comment: usually a bimetallic strip.

Comment: Quick search gives: https://youtu.be/BxS_lYqUKZY

Answer (score 1):

Usually, thermostats work with the principle of thermal expansion. There is a bimetallic strip that expands with heat and the connection is broken.

if you set it up so, that the expansion springs out of place (sort of like when you bend stick to use it as a launcher) , then you can reset the thermostat by mechanically "arming" it.

There are two main operating principles

- beam (Only in the resetable thermosta I would expect the bend to be downwards, and the reset to push it back into place).

[image]

- torsional spring: My guess is that this is the principle for the one you are showing.

[image]

Comment: Ok. The main reason i asked it was i wanted to know how the reset switch worked. Its so tiny i wonder if there some kind of spring. If someone has exact schematic or can fry open one. Pls share. Tnx.